# segueの戻り先を切り替える方法について

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

画面A、B、C、があり、Storyboardでセグエを使って画面遷移をさせたいと思っています。

遷移は、
　・画面A → C
　・画面B → C
があります。

このとき、画面Cで戻るボタンを押した時に「Aから来たならAに戻る」「Bから来たならBに戻る」としたいのですが、どうやれば良いのでしょうか。

Storyboardで画面Cの戻るボタンは、Exitに紐付けていますが、画面Aか画面Bのどちらかしか戻り先を選べません。

なお、「presentViewController」と「dismissViewControllerAnimated」などの方法ではなく、セグエでの方法を知りたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

1. Storyboard上で、`ViewController`と`Exit`を結んで、`Unwind Segue`を作成。
2. `Unwind segue`を選択して、Identifierを入力。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

3. `func performSegueWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String, sender sender: AnyObject?)`メソッドで、`Unwind Segue`による画面遷移ができる。

ちょっとざっくりしすぎる説明ですが、概要は理解いただけますか？

Comment: キャプチャまで貼っていただきありがとうございます！
お教えいただきました方法で無事に実現出来ました！